# Can object tagging be used with AWS Snowball Edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tagging, aws-snowball

Will be using a Snowball Edge to migrate some data. We want to use object tagging so that objects can transfer to AWS with their tags but not clear whether can do this on the Snowball?  Is there a standard way to handle this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it can't. A way round this is to create object tags as metadata for objects copied to Snowball and identify as such by a prefix, then create as object tags once in AWS using batch ops or a Lambda function.